# Will the unlockable styles still be able to be earned once season 7 has ended?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

As part of the battle pass for Season 7 there are two new skins unlocked straight away that have unlockable styles (others are unlocked later with more styles too). These are the Zenith and Lynx skins. The challenges to unlock all of the options are actually very time consuming and will be quite hard to earn.

Will the unlockable styles still be able to be earned once the season has ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/9kb6w0/will_the_dire_challenges_carry_over_for_next/) website, and my personal experience, the unlockable styles carry over to the next seasons. No need to rush them.

This has been since Season 5 and continues into future seasons.

Comment: Ah this is probably correct because checking it out I can still unlock stuff for Drfit (Season 5) but not Carbide (Season 4)... that's where the confusion came from. I missed season 6 to so missed experience from there to how they work now.

Comment: The XP you earned troughout season 6 did not carry over to the challenges that required a great amount of XP to unlock the styles. My guess is Epic got alot of negative feedback about this, and made the unlockable style challenges carry over to the next season.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just meant I didn't play during season 6 at all so I didn't realise the Season 5 style challenges had carried over and was still under the assumption it worked like in Season 4 (don't carry over).

Comment: No need for sorry. Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the question as answered for future references. :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The Carbide skin didn't carry over because they weren't XP based. You needed to do challenges related to the map, which changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, skin styles from one season can still be unlocked in another season, but sometimes it depends on the challenges. In Season X, some styles are unlocked using the weekly challenges, meaning those styles will not be unlockable after the season ends. However, if you have to gain XP, outlive opponents or carry out a certain action that you can still do in another season, it is possible to keep leveling up skins and to also get rewards like Back Blings, wraps, and harvesting tools after the season has ended.

Comment: So some will still be unlockable whereas others may not be?